# WPF MVVM ComboBox data binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, combobox

I am trying to create a simple WPF application and bind data to combobox but I am not having any luck. My PeriodList is getting populated fine but is not getting bind to the combobox. Do I need to set the DataContext in XAML or in code behind? Please help, I am very confused.

Here is my XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="FinancialControlApp.KeyClientReportView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FinancialControlApp"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" Width="630">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <!-- DataTemplate (View) -->
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:KeyClientReportModel}">
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <DockPanel Margin="20">
        <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock Margin="10,2" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text="Start Period" VerticalAlignment="Center" />

            <ComboBox Name="cmbStartPeriod" Margin="10,2" Width="112" VerticalAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding PeriodList}">
            </ComboBox>

            <TextBlock Margin="10,2" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text="End Period" VerticalAlignment="Center" />

            <ComboBox Name="cmbEndPeriod" Margin="10,2" Width="112" VerticalAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding PeriodList}" />

            <!--<Button Content="Save Product" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="10,2" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Command="{Binding Path=SaveProductCommand}" Width="100" />-->

            <Button Content="Run" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Margin="10,2" 
                        Command="{Binding Path=GetProductCommand}" IsDefault="True" Width="100" />
        </DockPanel>

        <!--<ContentControl Margin="10" Content="{Binding Path=PeriodName}" />-->
        <ContentControl Margin="10"></ContentControl>
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Here is my model

```
     namespace FinancialControlApp
    {
       public class KeyClientReportModel : ObservableObject
       {

        private string _periodName;

        public string PeriodName
        {
            get { return _periodName; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _periodName)
                {
                    _periodName = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("PeriodName");
                }
            }
        }

        List<KeyClientReportModel> _periodList = new List<KeyClientReportModel>();

        public List<KeyClientReportModel> PeriodList
        {
            get { return _periodList; }
            set
            {
                _periodList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("PeriodList");
            }
        }
      }
}
```

And here is my ViewModel

```
    namespace FinancialControlApp
{
    public class KeyClientReportViewModel : ObservableObject, IPageViewModel
    {
        private KeyClientReportModel _currentPeriod;
        private ICommand _getReportCommand;
        private ICommand _saveReportCommand;

        public KeyClientReportViewModel()
        {
            GetPeriod();
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return "Key Client Report"; }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<KeyClientReportModel> _periodName;
        public ObservableCollection<KeyClientReportModel> PeriodName
        {
            get { return _periodName; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _periodName)
                {
                    _periodName = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("PeriodName");
                }
            }
        }

        private void GetPeriod()
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            Helper_Classes.SQLHelper helper = new Helper_Classes.SQLHelper();

            ds = helper.getPeriod();
            dt = ds.Tables[0];
            PeriodName = new ObservableCollection<KeyClientReportModel>();
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                var period = dr["Period"].ToString();
                if (period != null)
                {
                    PeriodName.Add(new KeyClientReportModel { PeriodName = period });
                }
                //p.PeriodName = dr["Period"].ToString();           
            }
        }
}
}
```

UPDATE: So I attach a Value Converter to Break into the Debugger and here is what I see. I see

[I see 5 items in the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QacYu.png)

Comment: Are there any binding errors in the output window?

Comment: I dont see a public property named "KeyClientReportModel". You have only the collection of this type, but the binding says "KeyClientReportModel.PeriodList". The VIewmodel would expect a something like public KeyClientReportModel KeyClientReportModel { get; } (type equals property name)

Comment: For better practice, I recommend not binding to any properties in the Model, and only bind to properties in your ViewModel.  Your ViewModel must implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: I removed the reference to KeyClientModel in combobox binding, no luck. M3212V public class KeyClientReportViewModel : ObservableObject (This class implements INotifyPropertyChanged)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
ItemsSource="{Binding KeyClientReportModel.PeriodList}"
```

To:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding PeriodList}"
```

Make sure your `ViewModel` is set to the `DataContext` property of your view.

Set the combobox `DisplayMemberPath` to the property `Name` of your `KeyClientReportViewModel` class.

Or alternatively override the `.ToString()` method inside the `KeyClientReportViewModel` class in order to provide the `Combobox` item display text.

Comment: Jammer you said "Make sure your ViewModel is set to the DataContext property of your view."  How do I do that? Can you please help?

Comment: @user10946936 Where do you instantiate your ViewModel?  You may want to look into IOC. To keep it simple, if you instantiate your ViewModel in the code-behind of the user control, you can just set it there.

Comment: In the code behind     public partial class KeyClientReportView : UserControl
    {
        public KeyClientReportView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new KeyClientReportViewModel();
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

This can help you

------View

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        <!-- To get the ViewModel -->
        xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:WpfApp1.ViewModels"
        Title="MainWindow">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <!-- Assigning the ViewModel to the View -->
        <viewmodels:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Center"
               DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <TextBlock Margin="10,2"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                   Text="Start Period" />
        <ComboBox Name="cmbStartPeriod"
                  Width="112"
                  Margin="10,2"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding PeriodName}" // Items in the ViewModel 
                  DisplayMemberPath="Name"/> // Property to display
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

------- ViewModel

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        var items = new List<KeyClientReportModel>
        {
            new KeyClientReportModel
            {
                Name = "First",
                Value = 1
            },
            new KeyClientReportModel
            {
                Name = "Second",
                Value = 1
            }
        };

        PeriodName = new ObservableCollection<KeyClientReportModel>(items);
    }

    // You don't need to notify changes here because ObservableCollection 
    // send a notification when a change happens. 
    public ObservableCollection<KeyClientReportModel> PeriodName { get; set; }

}

public class KeyClientReportModel
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: When I change the View according to your suggestion xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FinancialControlApp.KeyClient" to point to my folder I get the error Undefined CLR namespace . If I keep it as xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FinancialControlApp" then I get an error at DataContext      <Window.DataContext>
        <local:KeyClientReportViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>                                                                                               Object Reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: What is your ViewModel namespace?

Comment: I have updated my code in my question. My ViewModel namespace is FinancialControlApp

Comment: Can you add a breakpoint int `GetPeriod()` to check if that method is called?

Comment: Yes, the GetPeriod() method is getting called and the PeriodName is getting populated with all the periods.

Comment: That means that the binding is working, your work now is to find the null object

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: The first thing is to debug the method `GetPeriod()` completely to check if it works ok.

Comment: I changed my GetPeriod() method to get the hardcoded values like you suggested in your MainWindowViewModel example and set the datacontext like     <UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:KeyClientReportViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext> still my combobox is empty

Comment: So I attach a Value Converter to Break into the Debugger. I have updated my question to add an image of what I see.